# Ads Click Through Prediction without Test Dataset

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-mining

I recently counter an assignment which is to predict whether users will click ads shown on some websites in the next week based on users' log history. The log contains *users' id*, *os* and *browser type*, *time*, *website id*, *ad id*, *click or not*, etc...

The problem is that this isn't a classification problem which I'm familiar with, because I don't know users' behaviour data in the next week(I mean there is no test dataset). So I'm confused and don't know where to start.

Should I simulate users' behaviour data(like when and uses what os and what browser to browse the website and so on...) first and then transform it into a classification problem? But how to simulate?

Any idea is welcome, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Simulation is probably not a good idea because you need to generate a function $f$ that will predict the presence of clicks. In the end, you performance will just measure how well you can approximate this particular $f$ that you simulated (and already know).

You can either report the scores obtained on **cross-validation** (the method is up to you) or you can split your train set into an actual train set, and a test set. The labels of the test set are just used to evaluate the performance of the model.